# Sorting by date descending and country ascending

Tags: mysql, sorting

In my database I have have the columns `date` and `country`. I want to select the data so that it is ascending by date and descending by country.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT supplier, spnn, date, country, networkname, mcc, mnc, oldprice, newprice, user
FROM supplierpricenotificationhistory
WHERE `supplier` = '6xx'
ORDER BY date DESC , country ASC
```

But it only orders the data in ascending order by date, and not in descending order by country.

```
for example (my coloumns in db)

Date              Country
15-4-2014         Bulgaria
16-4-2014         denmark
16-4-2014         Austria

for the above query it looks like this :

Date              Country
16-4-2014         Denmark
16-4-2014         Austria
15-4-2014         Bulgaria

i want like this

Date              Country
16-4-2014         Austria
16-4-2014         Denmark
15-4-2014         Bulgaria
```

Could someone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: If two date same then and then country will display in ascending order.

Comment: Just to elaborate on what @Sadikhasan said: If, and only if, two dates are the same then sorting by country is used.

Comment: Then invent an RDBMS :D

Comment: you can't have them both sorted on country and on date teh way you wnat them to, not without 2 queries, they are connected if you pull one of them up the other one that is connected will join